# \vspace in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, pdftex

I'm trying to produce some padding around a table in a beamer slide. I've tried using `\vspace{10mm}` but that doesn't seem to produce anything. Other vertical spacing commands such as `\bigskip` don't seem to work either.

I've searched but I can't seem to find any solution to this. I assume beamer manages its own vertical spacing, but surely there must be some way to override this?

The minimal example below shows the problem with the table being too close to the text above and below:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Results: School children}
    \begin{block}{Hypothesis}
        School closures may cause significant reductions in disease spread
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{Results}
    Worst case scenarios:
    \bigskip
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline \textbf{\% School Closure} & \textbf{Clinical Attack Rate} & \textbf{Mortality per 100,000} \\ 
\hline 0 & 30.6\% & 614 \\ 
\hline 100 & 0.6\% & 4 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} \\
    With 100\% school closure starting early (0.1\% of population symptomatic) mortality is reduced \textbf{below normal levels for US seasonal flu}

    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put empty lines (aka paragraph breaks) before and after the tabular.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Results: School children}
    \begin{block}{Hypothesis}
        School closures may cause significant reductions in disease spread
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{Results}
    Worst case scenarios:

    \bigskip
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline \textbf{\% School Closure} & \textbf{Clinical Attack Rate} & \textbf{Mortality per 100,000} \\ 
\hline 0 & 30.6\% & 614 \\ 
\hline 100 & 0.6\% & 4 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}

    \bigskip
    With 100\% school closure starting early (0.1\% of population symptomatic) mortality is reduced \textbf{below normal levels for US seasonal flu}

    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

In general, make sure you have a new line before the `\vspace` (or `\bigskip`) command, for instance:

This won't work:

```
    Worst case scenarios:
    \vspace{1cm}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
```

This will:

```
    Worst case scenarios:

    \vspace{1cm}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}.
```

Comment: How is this any different from @HaraldHanche-Olsen answer?  you are just using `\vspace` as the example whereas he used `\bigskip` but the moral is the same use space.

Comment: @dustin I agree to some extent, however the reason I posted this answer is that I had a similar problem (with an image, not a tabular environment) and this was the first page I landed on however HaraldHanche-Olsen's answer did not help me for two reasons - 1. the first line of the answer seems to imply that the empty lines should go before/after the tabular (which is incorrect), and since my problem didn't include a tabular environment I thought it did not apply. 2. The answer also included the entirety of the OP's file, and so I did not even notice that change.

Comment: I am happy to make my answer CW, since I don't particularly care about earning reputation, just wanted to help others who may have read the other answer as I did and thought it did not apply.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to break a paragraph, you can use `\\[size]`

```
...
\begin{block}{Results}
Worst case scenarios:\\[2ex]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Commands: \bigskip, \medskip, \smallskip need to set frame as fragile

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Vertical spaces}
  Text \bigskip

  Text
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Neither `\bigskip`, `\medskip` or `\smallskip` need a fragile frame. They are perfectly safe to use in normal frames.